# Auto-populate Java Login details from bash

Tags: java, bash, auto-populate

I have to run the same java-based program every day from a Linux command prompt.  I would like to somehow auto-populate my login and password into the pop-up window.  Is that at all possible?  I've tried:

```
./SuperAdmin <<EOF
username
password
EOF
```

and

```
echo -e "username\npassword\n" | ./SuperAdmin
```

and

```
./SuperAdmin <<<$(printf "username\npassword\n")
```

None of these work.

It's like once the java program has begun to run, control is taken by the program, and nothing can be done to populate the un:pw fields from bash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that Java program in the question as a [mcve]. Does it even read from stdin? If that program expects input in a GUI, it's likely it does not support this way of working and you'll have to modify the code to either accept command line arguments or read from stdin. This could not be desirable as it can be a security problem when your credentials show up in log files like command history and the `ps` output.

Comment: Look into `expect`